# Applying decimal place change in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I am trying to visualize the decimals of the data in column TPvsTIM. This column's data is the result of the following:

TPvsTIM = Temps_TP / ToBreak (*both being long integers with numeric values*)

Here is a picture of my table [image]

Comment: Your TPvsTIM column is storing integer data so your values are being rounded when you do the calculation.  Create a new column and ensure it is type double.  Recalculate.

Comment: That works! Thank you for the quick answer.